# Accidently deleted iPhone from Organizer in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I accidently deleted my iPhone from Device section in Organizer (in Xcode).

How do I get it back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it not just re-appear when you plug your phone in?

Reboot everything and try again.

Ok now you have a problem. :)